# Why is my clan not showing up in Clash of Clans

Tags: clash-of-clans

A lot of people joined our clan and now it doesn't want to show anything. I can't leave, edit, send mail, or anything.

I'm stuck in a clan. There was the strangest bug ever. There were 51/50 clan members. I was waiting at least 15 minutes for something to show up, now we can't even start the war. We can only talk but not in our language.

Comment: "we can only talk but not in our language." What's that mean? What's your language? What do you end up talking in?

Comment: Are you able to kick people?

Comment: Screenshot maybe?